# How do I find what is the value of offset of this byte?

Tags: perl

So somehow from the following hex data `(03 00 21 04 80 04)` the values below were obtained.

Can anybody can tell how how can I do this and how it was achieved?

```
Band                                 = 3  (40,6)
Duplex_Mode                          = 0  (46,1)
Result                               = 0  (47,1)
Reserved_1                           = 0  (48,8)
Min_Search_Half_Frames               = 1  (56,5)
Min_Search_Half_Frames_Early_Abort   = 1  (61,5)
Max_Search_Half_Frames               = 1  (66,5)
Max_PBCH_Frames                      = 0  (71,5)
Number_of_Blocked_Cells              = 0  (76,3)
Number_PBCH_Decode_Attemp_Cells      = 1  (79,3)
Number_of_Search_Results             = 1  (82,4)
Reserved_2                           = 0  (86,2)
```

The parameters in paranthesis is the Offset/Length I am told. I don't understand how based on that information should I be able to unpack this payload.

So I have written

```
my $data = pack ('C*', map hex, split /\s+/, "03 00 21 04 80 04");
($tmp1, $Reserved_1, $tmp2) = unpack("C C V", $data);
```

And now help. How do I unpack the table values above from `$tmp1` and `$tmp2` ?

EDIT: Hex Data = `"00 00 00 7F 08 03 00 21 04 80 04 FF D7 FB 0C EC 01 44 00 61 1D 00 00 10 3B 00 00 FF D7 FB 0C 00 00 8C 64 00 00 EC 45"`

Thanks!

Comment: I just checked, and it should i believe. Hmm. I get how value 3 is obtained from binary `000011` from hex `03` for Band and Duplex and Result are the remaining two bits. I am asking only how does one go about unpacking the bits? To extract a packed field, first mask off everything but the desired bits and then shift them down to the LSB. For example, to get the value packed in the upper 6 bits of some byte in `$foo`: `my $field = ($foo & 0xfc) >> 2;`

Comment: `my $data = pack 'C*', map hex, map "".reverse($_), split /\s+/, "00 00 00 7F 08 03 00 21 04 80 04 FF D7 FB 0C EC 01 44 00 61 1D 00 00 10 3B 00 00 FF D7 FB 0C 00 00 8C 64 00 00 EC 45";`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to define a set of bitmasks, and use bitwise AND operations to unpack your data.